# How do I calcuate zoom from pinch event using expo camera?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, pinchzoom, expo-camera

As far as I googled, zooming with two fingers is called pinch gesture (correct me if I am wrong). Also, as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628663/how-would-you-implement-pinch-zoom-in-react-native) I have to use `PinchGestureHandler` from `react-native-gesture-handler` library in order to detect this gesture.
Again, as suggested via one of the answers, I need to use:

```
<PinchGestureHandler
    onGestureEvent={this.onPinchGestureEvent}
  >
    <View>
          <Camera
              type={cameraType}
              flashMode={flashMode}
              //I need to set my zoom here
              zoom={zoom}
              style={styles.preview}
              ref={camera => this.camera = camera}
          />
    </View>
        </PinchGestureHandler>

onPinchGestureEvent = event => {
      console.log(event.nativeEvent.scale);
      //somehow I need to set my zoom here
    }
```

When I `console.log(event.nativeEvent)` from my `onPinchGestureEvent` method I get the following output:

```
onPinchGestureEvent event:  Object {
  "focalX": 216.5,
  "focalY": 212.5,
  "handlerTag": 8,
  "numberOfPointers": 2,
  "scale": 0.6020446981019169,
  "state": 4,
  "velocity": -0.0031890643353418226,
}
```

I tried to set up my zoom based on the scale:

```
const onPinchGestureEvent = (event) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.scale >= 1) {
      setZoom(1);
    } else if (event.nativeEvent.scale <= 0) {
      setZoom(0);
    } else {
      setZoom(event.nativeEvent.scale);
    }
  };
```

But it didnt give me smooth results, also I can not zoom out.
There is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368597/expo-camera-zoom) too  which essentially is the same, but no one answered.
According to this [blog](https://blog.synced.to/RN-Pinch-To-Zoom/) I need something like the following:

```
calculateZoom(touch0x, touch0y, touch1x, touch1y) {
    const x = touch0x - touch1x;
    const y = touch0y - touch1y;

    const distance = Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2);
    
    return Math.sqrt(distance);
  }
```

but from my `console.log(event.nativeEvent)` I have only one `focalX` and one `focalY` value.

Any suggestions, blogs, ideas will be grant!

Answer (score 4):

This is my proposed solution

```
const onPinchGestureEvent = (nativeEvent) => {
 var scale = nativeEvent.nativeEvent.scale
 var velocity = nativeEvent.nativeEvent.velocity / 20

  let newZoom =
  velocity > 0
  ? zoom + scale * velocity * (Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0.01 : 25)
  : zoom -
    scale * Math.abs(velocity) * (Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0.02 : 50);

 if (newZoom < 0) newZoom = 0;
 else if (newZoom > 0.5) newZoom = 0.5;

 setZoom(newZoom)
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72517845/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).